# How to connect two switches together

Tags: switch

I am a novice so please bear with me.

At work we have a Cisco SG200-50P (which is connected to our router and server)

I just bought a Engenius EGS2110P that I want to add to our network.

How do I do this please? Do I just get a CAT5e and connect it to a empty port on each switch and then it will work? Or do I have to use the Link/Act ports, or something else?

Cheers, Roger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to bring cat 5 (cat 6 preferred as it is 1G BW) and connect the two switches to each other and then log to each one (using the GUI)and configure the ports involved in this connection as a trunk , ***change the management IP of the two switches*** to be in the same range to be able to manage them from any where .

***NOTE:*** if you connected the two switches to each other directly without trunk configuration , it will work but under the consideration of you run single vlan which is called   ***spread network*** but this solution is not standered and not recommended as well

Answer (score 2):

Certainly, the ports need to be enabled before the link will work.

You should enable trunking on the ports connecting the two switches. How many VLANs do you have configured on the Cisco, and do you want all of them to be available on the Engenius? You can limit which VLANs cross the trunk.